# Why is MySQL performing a filesort on this query?

Tags: mysql, indexing, filesort

Why is MySQL performing a filesort on this query? I'm expecting simply `Using where`:

```
SELECT * FROM active_campaign_days
WHERE ad_unit_id=1
AND day='2017-12-10'
ORDER BY bid DESC, budget DESC, campaign_id ASC
```

Index on `(ad_unit_id, day, bid, budget, campaign_id)` - the database is using this index according to the `EXPLAIN`.

In this particular result set, `bid` and `budget` are the same for all rows. `(ad_unit_id, campaign_id)` is unique.

EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  active_campaign_days    ref     ad_unit_id,ad_unit_id_2     ad_unit_id_2    7   const,const     5   Using where; Using filesort
```

Comment: *filesort is badly named. Anytime a sort can’t be performed from an index, it’s a filesort. It has nothing to do with files. Filesort should be called “sort.” It is quicksort at heart.* https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/ - It took me like 15 seconds to google that. Please take the time to reasearch before you add questions

Comment: I know what a mysql filesort is. I'm asking why can't MySQL utilize the index fully. If you read my question thoroughly instead of jumping to conclusions you would have seen that I was expecting `Using where`, MySQL's indication that it used the index without performing any extra sorting.

Comment: @juergend - thanks for the link; I was wondering where I had discovered the mention of qsort.  I have many times said that "filesort" is not as evil as it sounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's dissect the query..

1. The `WHERE ad_unit_id=1 AND day='2017-12-10'` needs an index starting with `ad_unit_id` and `day` (in either order).  This will provide optimal filtering.
2. If practical, all the `ORDER BY` can be added to that `INDEX` so that it can avoid having to sort the data.  But there is an issue with `ORDER BY bid DESC, budget DESC, campaign_id ASC`.  Note that there is a mixture of `DESC` and `ASC`.  MySQL can only scan an index in one direction.  This implies that all must be `ASC` or all must be `DESC`.  (See note below)  So, `INDEX(ad_unit, day, bid, budget, campaign_id)` is not as useful as you would like.
3. If the Optimizer could get past step 2, then adding any other columns mentioned *anywhere* in the `SELECT` (namely all of `*`), then the index would be come "covering".  This gives a different variety of performance boost -- by doing all the work in the index, not having to touch the 'data'.

Note:  Beginning with Version 8.0, MySQL will honor `DESC` in index declarations.  So, you could say `INDEX(ad_unit, day, bid DESC, budget DESC, campaign_id ASC)`, and the Optimizer could use it *without sorting* in item 2, above.  (Pre-8.0, `DESC` was allowed, but ignored, in index declarations.)

Workaround?  It would change the order of the output, but you might accept having all the columns `ASC` (or all `DESC`)?

Meanwhile, `INDEX(ad_unit_id, day)` is about all that is worth having.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware that you couldn't mix sort directions in this way prior to Version 8.0. I'm using Version 5.6 so unfortunately updating the index declaration is not an option. Setting all sorts to DESC did eliminate the filesort, however. I'll probably update my backend to use an inverse value for the last sort key.

Comment: @Dan - You _can_ mix them; and you _do_ get the desired ordering, but no index will help you, and a "sort" will be done.  I would not add code to the backend unless the performance difference is enough to be of concern.  (I suspect the sort does not hurt that much.)